# Pass along a Python type to C++ that inherits C++

Tags: cpython, pybind11

I have a C++ class `RuleSet` with a bunch of `std::shared_ptr` to some rules for a game, most notably to the victory condition, a `std::shared_ptr<VictoryRule>`. `VictoryRule` is a abstract C++ type, with one function `winners` to return the winners of a game. (`team_t` is a enum, but for simplicity consider it an alias to `int`.)

```cpp
class VictoryRule {
 public:
  //! @brief Check if game is won by a team.
  //! @return the teamno of the team that won or team_t::no_team if nobody won.
  virtual std::vector<team_t> winners(const Game &game) = 0;
  //! @brief Default virtual destructor.
  virtual ~VictoryRule() = default;
};
```

I exposed this class to python with pybind11 to be able to subclass it in python, with a trampoline class.

```cpp
class PyVictoryRule : public VictoryRule {
 public:
  std::vector<team_t> winners(const Game &game) override {
    PYBIND11_OVERRIDE_PURE(std::vector<team_t>, VictoryRule, winners, game);
  }
};
```

And it's registered with:

```
  pybind11::class_<VictoryRule, PyVictoryRule, std::shared_ptr<VictoryRule>>(
      m, "VictoryRule")
      .def(pybind11::init())
      .def("winners", &VictoryRule::winners, arg("game"));
```

And I'v reimplemented the Rule in python

```py
class CustomVictoryRule(VictoryRule):
    def __init__(self):
        VictoryRule.__init__(self)

    def winners(self, game):
        return [1]
```

I can instantiate the class in python and call the `winners` method without any issue.

```py
cvr = CustomVictoryRule()
cvr.winners() # Returns [1]
```

But I don't want to use the rule directly, I want to store it in the C++ Ruleset.

```cpp
class RuleSet {
 public:
  std::shared_ptr<VictoryRule> get_victory_rule();
  void register_victory_rule(std::shared_ptr<VictoryRule> victory_rule);

 private:
  std::unordered_map<CasePawn::Type, std::shared_ptr<Rule>> per_pawn_type_rule_;
  std::shared_ptr<VictoryRule> victory_rule_;
};
```

All methods of RuleSet are registered to pybind11 as-is.

```cpp
  pybind11::class_<RuleSet, std::shared_ptr<RuleSet>>(m, "RuleSet")
      .def(pybind11::init())
      .def("get_victory_rule", &RuleSet::get_victory_rule)
      .def("register_victory_rule", &RuleSet::register_victory_rule,
           arg("victory_rule"));
```

But when I pass along a `CustomVictoryRule` to `RuleSet.register_victory_rule`, it loses its dynamic type, and Receive an error for trying to call pure virtual function `VictoryRule::winners`...

```py
ruleset = RuleSet()
ruleset.register_victory_rule(CustomVictoryRule())
ruleset.get_victory_rule().winners() #fails with RuntimeError: `Tried to call pure virtual function "VictoryRule::winners"`
```

What should I do so that ruleset.get_victory_rule() return a victory rule with the correct type CustomVictoryRule, so that CustomVictoryRule.winners() is called in that last line of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Instead of doing:

```
ruleset.register_victory_rule(CustomVictoryRule())
```

I do:

```
cvr = CustomVictoryRule()
ruleset.register_victory_rule(cvr)
```

Then it worked ! So somehow python keeps alive the instance when it's stored into a local variable that's kept alive as long as the `ruleset`.

Thus, I need to tell pybind11 to keep temporary python objects passed as arguments. Luckily, there's a `pybind11::keep_alive` decorator to functions to [do exactly that](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html#keep-alive). So, binding `RuleSet` from c++ to python with the following fixes the issue !

```
  pybind11::class_<RuleSet, std::shared_ptr<RuleSet>>(m, "RuleSet")
      .def(pybind11::init())
      .def("victory_rule", &RuleSet::get_victory_rule)
      .def("register_victory_rule", &RuleSet::register_victory_rule,
           arg("victory_rule"), keep_alive<1, 2>());
```